# How to refresh a bootstrap modal after I created a record*

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-modal

I let the user to create comments within a modal. At the same time I show the comments within the same modal.

Also there is a form to create a new comment.

The only issue is, how can I only refresh the modal after the user clicks on the "Send comment" button? Just like this: https://trello.com/c/E8K0kxr0/9-teardowns

The modal shouldn't be closed of course.

I put questions marks because I don't know where to redirect or what to do...

My comments_controller is:

```
def new
    @comment = current_user.comments.build
  end

  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id if current_user
    @comment.save
    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Success!"
      ??????????????????
    else
      flash[:success] = "error!"
      ??????????????????
    end
  end
```

Comment: You need to use ajax calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, your `create` actions will respond with JS, meaning you'll need to have a `create.js.erb` o `create.js.haml`.  IF you are using a partial to populate the modal, this is all very simple, as you'll just recall the same partial with the new data.

The best way to go about things like this is to have a partial that renders each record, i.e., `_comment.html.erb` - in which you define the layout of an individual comment.  The you can just append an individual comment to your list.

An example would be *create.js.haml*:

```
$('.modal-body ul.class-containting-your-list').append( "#{escape_javascript( render '/comments/comment')}");
```